# Getopt doesn't seem to recognise arguments

Tags: c++, getopt

I'm starting a new project in C++, I started by creating a function that handles command line arguments using getopt, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm afraid it is a small mistake, but I've been debugging the code for a while and I still don't understand why it isn't working.
The problem is that when running the program it doesn't enter any of the switch cases when I run the program with those flags.

Here's the code:

```
bool verbose = false;

void commandlinearguments (int argc, char** argv, char** word_file_name, char** GSport) {

    int opt;

    sprintf(*GSport, "%d", 58000+GN);

    while ( opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:v") != -1 ) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 'p':
                cout << optarg << endl;
                *GSport = optarg;
                break;
            case 'v':
                verbose = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    if ( argv[optind] != NULL ) {
        *word_file_name = argv[optind];
    } else {
        cout << "Word file not specified. Aborting." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return;

}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    char* GSport = new char[6];
    char* word_file_name = NULL;

    commandlinearguments(argc, argv, &word_file_name, &GSport);
    cout << word_file_name <<endl;
    cout << GSport << endl;
    cout << verbose << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I'm compiling like this:

```
g++ server.cpp -o gs -g
```

And when I run `./gs wf -p 12345 -v` the output is:

```
wf
58003
0
```

Anyone can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you are getting downvotes probably becuase this is incomplete code, whats GN for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:v") != -1
```

is the same as

```
opt = (getopt(argc, argv, "p:v") != -1)
```

so `opt` is 0 or 1 depending on whether the result was -1. You probably meant

```
(opt = getopt(argc, argv, "p:v")) != -1
```

which assigns the result to `opt` and *then* checks whether it was -1.